# Meteor.js with React - Why does the html page not render when I use .jsx, it only renders with .js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, meteor

I am following the official tutorial from this link:
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

I created my own project with a command in the terminal:
`meteor create --react new-react-app`

The command generated the file structure like in the tutorial only instead of getting imports/ui/App.js and /imports/ui/Task.js I got App.jsx and Task.jsx.

The problem is that the html file does not render the list when I start the server. Only if I change those files in a regular .js it works. Why?

Shouldn't we use .jsx, afterall I have chosen the project with React.js?

Comment: The `.jsx` extension is pretty much obsolete these days.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. So in 2019, we can write React code in a file with `.js` extension?